# What is the most Pythonic way of filling left-NaN's only with zeros?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to optimize a numpy function to fill part of an array. It takes a 1D `np.array()` with `nan`'s inside. Some of them are all on the left side, and I want *just them* to be filled with zeros. Example:

from this:

```
np.array([ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, 8, 9, np.nan ])
```

I want to get this:

```
np.array([ 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, 8, 9, np.nan ])
```

Other "internal" missing values should remain untouched, I will process them differently.

What is the most Pythonic way to do that?

Comment: Maybe the best way is to do it while "processing the internal missing values". But it depends on what this processing is exactly.

Comment: yeah my problem is how to do it without using loops or similarly "slow" ways. I have to process a lot of data and I want to cut computational times.

Comment: Sure, that is an excellent idea. But the best way may still be to do it during the processing of the other values. Hard to say if we do not know what this "processing" is exactly.

Comment: Oh I'm using an imputation technique based on my current statistical analysis. But it's completely unrelated with this zero filling I want on the left. These are time series data, I know for sure that NaN's on the left are there because some trends started later, while NaN's within the trend are another kind of missing data that required statistical imputation. But this is not related with my question.

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution as above, using `np.min` and `np.where` instead of `max` and `np.argmax`.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, 8, 9, np.nan ])

x[0:np.min(np.where(~np.isnan(x)))] = 0
```

I would argue that this is *ever so slightly* more readable, as in the sentence "Set all values from index 0 to the minimum index where the value is not nan to zero".

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

x=np.array([ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, 8, 9, np.nan ])

x[0:max(np.argmax(~np.isnan(x)),0)]=0
```

Outputs:

```py
[ 0.  0.  0.  3.  4.  5. nan  7.  8.  9. nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found a solution myself:

```
def left_zero_fill(x):
    if np.isfinite(x[0]): return x

    cumsum = np.cumsum(np.isnan(x))    
    x[ :np.argmax(cumsum[:-1]==cumsum[1:]) +1] = 0
    return x
```

They have very similar execution times. The differences are minimal and they all work. Thank you all for the help.

---

EDIT:
substituting `not np.isnan` with `np.isfinite` made it the fastest implementation.